# issue in getting dex file while adding google play service and osm jar android

Tags: android, google-play-services, openstreetmap, osmdroid

i m implement osm app with google play store so i add below jars.

When i run my project i getting below error

```
Error Code:2

Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/notifications/json/gson/GsonNotificationCallback;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pkg.name"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile project(':mapsForgeForOsmdroid')
compile project(':oSMBonusPack')
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0'
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
 compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
 compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
 compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
/*    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile files('libs/google-api-client-appengine-1.20.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.20.0 (2).jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-gson-1.19.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev133-1.20.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.20.0 (1).jar')*/
   //compile files('libs/google-api-client-util-1.2.1-alpha.jar')
}
```

Comment: Post `build.gradle file` directly. Image is not that's clear.

Comment: M D : see build.gradle file in my question

Comment: why you add two times `compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'` ?

Comment: Where i put two times ` compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'`?

Answer (score 0):

I think OsmBonusPack brings in a copy of Gson. Try adding an exclusion for it.

Edit:
You can find the offending library using

`gradle dependencies`

once it's located, you can exclude it using (a few examples)

```
   compile('group:artifact:version') {  
     exclude module: 'cglib' //by artifact name 
     exclude group: 'org.jmock' //by group
     exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'iAmBuggy' //by both name and group
}
```

Comment: 13 mins ago was a comment. now it is an answer!